# Using Twig in global custom text to check for a specific content type

Tags: views, theming, 9

I am filtering for two content types to display in a view: *Artwork Page* and *Cover Page*. I want to change the HTML markup for *Cover Page*.

I have researched and tried many field names for *Content Type*, but with none of them I get what I am trying to achieve. In this instance, the replacement pattern for *Content Type* is `{{ type }}`; using it doesn't work. I've tried both the machine name (*cover_page*) and the name (*Cover Page*), but neither of them worked.

```
{% if type == 'cover_page' %}
  <h1>THIS IS THE BEGINNING</h1>
{% endif %}

{% if type == 'Cover Page' %}
  <h1>THIS IS THE BEGINNING</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I can't tell if you're trying to use this token in a custom text within a views area, e.g. header or footer, or as one of the fields in the row display. _I don't believe_ you'll be able to use a field's token value in a header / footer custom text as it won't have the proper context to generate a value (the value could be different for each result in your view).

Answer (score 0):

The content type field is a reference field and contains the machine name of the content type as target id.

Configure the field formatter *Entity ID*:

> Configure field: Content: Content type
>
> **Formatter**
> Entity ID  ▼

Or use the property target_id when rewriting the field itself:

```
{{ type__target_id }}
```

You can add a second instance of the field and hide it if you only want to use the machine name for logic and don't want to display it.

Comment: Thank you 4k4. The Formatter label did it! All I needed was the machine name for the twig test.